Moral laws are by definiton how one ought to behave. How can it have no empirical part?
I am beginning to read Groundwork to the Metaphysic of Morals where Kant sets out on removing everything empirical from moral philosophy and thus arrive at the fundamental principle governing it, which therefore is purely rational.
My question is, since ethics is the study of what people ought to do, doesn't moral philosophy have an inextricable empirical component? The whole of ethics seems to rest on empirical grounds.

The empirical component is in the hypothetical imperative, not in Kantian categorical imperative derived from his grounding metaphysics already subsuming the hypothetical...

How can what people ought to do rest on empirical grounds? Empirical grounds can tell us what is out there, what people do, what people can do given what is, but how can they tell us what people ought to do? At most, they can tell us what people ought to do in order to achieve some end, and if that's what you mean by "empirical part" then Kant fully admits it in means-end reasoning. But nothing empirical can tell us what that end itself ought to be and that is the "fundamental principle" he is after, split off from the "empirical part".

Moral philosophy builds on the ontological and epistemological grounding of who ever professes the specific moral theory. If they accept any form of ontological dualism, a non-empirical, logically consistent moral theory can be developed. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/ if interested.

"since ethics is the study of what people ought to do, doesn't moral philosophy have an inextricable empirical component" - the usage of "since" implies the latter might or does follow from the former. But it doesn't. Why do you think it does or might?


doesn't moral philosophy have an inextricable empirical component? == I should think that's obvious. You think that's obvious. It seems to have eluded Kant


@NotThatGuy My reasoning wasn't complete. I meant that 'ought' always refers to an end that is to be achieved. This end is, most likely, an empirical outcome(let's say, order and peace in a society). So, moral philosophy is inextricably linked to its end, which if empirical, cannot be possibly studied by 'removing everything empirical', as Kant sets out to do.

@Conifold Thank you for your answer. You pinpointed exactly where I was getting at. This still seems very counterintuitive to me, as I have always thought of morality as serving some practical end.

The empirical part is about figuring out what's true and how our actions will and do affect that (which is epistemology).
But those are all "is" statements, and you can't get an "ought" from an "is", as Hume famously said.
Whether you consider the "is" part to be part of moral philosophy, whether you consider the "oughts" to be built on top of that, or whether you consider the two to be independent - that may be little more than an issue of semantics, which doesn't change the underlying issue that you can't get an "ought" from an "is".

The line between epistemology and moral philosophy might blur a bit if you consider, as I do, that we carry moral responsibility for our epistemology, for questioning our beliefs, for looking for justification for them, and for rejecting unjustified beliefs. It would be a problem to reject that idea, because many acts we consider immoral may follow logically from illogical or unjustified beliefs. It would greatly limit our ability to say what's right and wrong.
Although, while this does connect epistemology and moral philosophy more closely, there is still a separation between "is" and "ought". We "ought" to question what we believe is the case - that's still not an "is" statement.
* In modern society, it seems far too common (from all sides) for people to assume others have similar beliefs and are acting maliciously, rather than them having different beliefs. This assumption often seems unjustified, and if it's incorrect, it would greatly impede your efforts (and any other efforts, potentially) to get them to stop acting the way they do.
